# How can I install pyodbc on Windows for use with Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm getting error on pyodbc install, i was studyng the problem and maybe its the c++ redistribute instalation problem, but even with c++ redistribute intalation updated the problem oc

Follow the error when o try to install pyodbc

```
C:\Users\MacInBox>pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/29/aa190749bac37ede0f11a68a75e7055254699c11572bd94213f1163dfd8f/pyodbc-4.0.27.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\macinbox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MacInBox\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ysm4ul3_\\pyodbc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MacInBox\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ysm4ul3_\\pyodbc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MacInBox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fzctfb9u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\MacInBox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ysm4ul3_\pyodbc\
    Complete output (12 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.27 -Ic:\users\macinbox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\macinbox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" /EHsc /Tpsrc\buffer.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src\buffer.obj /Wall /wd4514 /wd4820 /wd4668 /wd4711 /wd4100 /wd4127 /wd4191
    buffer.cpp
    C:\Users\MacInBox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ysm4ul3_\pyodbc\src\pyodbc.h(19): fatal error C1083: NÆo ‚ poss¡vel abrir arquivo incluir: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\macinbox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MacInBox\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ysm4ul3_\\pyodbc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MacInBox\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ysm4ul3_\\pyodbc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MacInBox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fzctfb9u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Here are the c++ reditribute installed at my pc
[image: Here are tge b]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, pyodbc on PiPI (pyodbc 4.0.27) does not have wheel files for Python 3.8, so when you do `pip install pyodbc` pip will try to build pyodbc from source. You don't need C++ *redistributables* for that, you need a C++ *compiler*.

The next release of pyodbc will almost certainly have pre-compiled wheel files for Python 3.8. In the meantime you can download the required wheel file from

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc)

and then install it with

```
pip install C:\path\to\pyodbc-4.0.27-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

**Update 2020-06-30:** Current versions of pyodbc now have wheels for Python 3.8.

Comment: Heeeey!!! Thanks!!!! I've downloaded and tried with pip install C:\path\to\with pyodbc‑4.0.27‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl and i solved the problem!! thks!!!

Comment: I have been searching for this almost for 3 hours straight. pyodbc should update its resources.